# 4 column does not align correct with bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to make a grid containing a banner and 4 columns. The example can be [seen here](http://vouzalis.dk/test.html).

The space between the lines are 10px, but I cannot make the boxes fit so they are following the line in the grid. When I look at the code it is looking correct to me. So I was thinking it could be the size of the pictures the was to small. But changing the size does not solve my problem.

Does anybody knows how I can make my grid elements fit the below lines on the picture?

[image]

**My code:**
(I have cut away some HTML code there is not relevant for the question)

```css
/* Card and Button */

    body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    div { 
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .index-content {
      /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
      /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
    }

    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 350px;
    }

    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }

    /* Set width between block elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }

    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .index-content .col-lg-4 {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        
        .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
        }
    
        div { 
            background-color: #fff;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }
        .row [class*="col-"] {
          padding-left: 5px;
          padding-right: 5px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .card {
            position: relative;
        }
        .card-content {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        .card-content h4,
        .card-content p {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }
        .card-content a {
            float: right;
        }
        .index-content .card h4,
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 0 20px 15px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 991px) {
        .medium-padding.top {
           padding-top:10px;
        }

        .medium-padding.bottom {
            padding-bottom:10px;
        } 
        .medium-padding.left {
            padding-left:5px;
        }

        .medium-padding.right {
            padding-right:5px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Col md 3 - 3 - 3 - 3 + Col sm 6 -6 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding bottom left medium-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding left bottom medium-padding right bottom left">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding left bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 small-padding right bottom ">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="1" class="img-responsive center-block"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="2" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right left bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="3" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="4" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right left bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Sorry - Bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove all style you write for col-*-* and row. Use this style for that

```
.margin_bottom{margin-bottom:10px;}
.row [class*="col-"]{ padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; }
.row { margin-left: -5px; margin-right: -5px; }
```

And use this html code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 margin_bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 margin_bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 margin_bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 margin_bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="1" class="img-responsive center-block"></img>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="2" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="3" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="4" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution. The only thing there is missing is the banner 600x400px there is not aligning in the bottom. Should I change the size of that, or what is the correct way to do this? http://vouzalis.dk/test.html

Comment: yes we provide 10 px margin for the 300*205 images so we need to reduce the image 300*200

Comment: I tried to changes the images to 200px, but that does not change the difference unfortunately.

Comment: if we reduce the height of the 205 images to 195, then border bottom take 10px so the structure will be the height 400, that's equal to the 600*400 image

Answer (score 4):

Please don't use the class "col-" with the class "row" for same element.

Like this.

```
<div class="row col-sm-6">
```

Because class name "row" had margin-right:-15px; and margin-left:-15px; If you use class name "col-" it will affect the row style with padding-right:15px; and padding-left:15px;

This is the main reason for this issue, Please add one more div structure like following method

```
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
     <div class="row"> 

     </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I just updated my code with your change. I also updated the link to the demo version. I am having to much padding to the right now. But I can change that with the height/width now?

Comment: That is looking perfect. Are you making a row for the 2 of the small columns, or how are you doing this?

Comment: I just post another answer for this question with my code please look up and use this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of problems with your code.

One of them is that you use BS3 and not 4. BS3 is using `float` which is a bad practice. Please use BS4 with flex. Everything is much easier.

Another one is that you use 2 completely different classes on the same element. `row` and `col-` should never be used on the same element. In your case you need row inside the column.

I changed that in your html and added some css at the top of the file. This should help you achieve what you want.

Again i stress out that you should use BS4.

```css
/* Card and Button */
    .row.mx-0 {
      margin-left:0;
      margin-right:0;
    }
    .row .col-sm-6.no-padding {
      padding-right:0;
      padding-left:0;
    }
    .row .col-sm-6.no-bottom {
    padding-bottom:0;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    div { 
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .index-content {
      /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
      /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
    }

    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 350px;
    }

    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }

    /* Set width between block elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }

    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .index-content .col-lg-4 {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        
        .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
        }
    
        div { 
            background-color: #fff;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }
        .row [class*="col-"] {
          padding-left: 5px;
          padding-right: 5px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .card {
            position: relative;
        }
        .card-content {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        .card-content h4,
        .card-content p {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }
        .card-content a {
            float: right;
        }
        .index-content .card h4,
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 0 20px 15px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 991px) {
        .medium-padding.top {
           padding-top:10px;
        }

        .medium-padding.bottom {
            padding-bottom:10px;
        } 
        .medium-padding.left {
            padding-left:5px;
        }

        .medium-padding.right {
            padding-right:5px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Col md 3 - 3 - 3 - 3 + Col sm 6 -6 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding bottom left medium-padding right bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding left bottom medium-padding right bottom left">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding left bottom">
            <div class="index-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 small-padding right bottom no-bottom">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="1" class="img-responsive center-block"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">
        <div class="row mx-0">
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="2" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right left bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="3" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="4" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right left bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time. I am programming for a site that have around 20.000 sites in the domain. Therefore it is not possible just to change the Bootstrap to version 4 yet. 

Your suggestion seems to solve a lot of the problem. The only thing that annoys me alot, is that the banner has to have a height on 581px. to align with the 4 boxes. http://vouzalis.dk/test.html. Is there a way to make that a nice even number? Fx 580px, 600px etc?

Comment: you can tweak the padding for that. For example for the first 2 small boxes instead of `padding-bottom:15px` use `padding-bottom:14px`.

Answer (score 0):

@MK-DK please never use `row` and `col` to-gether in a div. please check the below example for a working fix with minor changes to you html and css.

```css
/* Card and Button */

.row.mx-0 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row .col-sm-6.no-padding {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row .col-sm-6.no-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-content a {
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 350px;
}

.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}

/* Set width between block elements */

.small-padding.top {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.small-padding.bottom {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.small-padding.left {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.small-padding.right {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.row [class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

/* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .index-content .col-lg-4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  div {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  .row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .medium-padding.top {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .medium-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .medium-padding.left {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  .medium-padding.right {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}

/* Custom css added to fix the margin */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-small-gutters {
    margin: 0 -5px !important
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Col md 3 - 3 - 3 - 3 + Col sm 6 -6 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding right bottom">
      <div class="index-content">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg">
          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding bottom left medium-padding right bottom">
      <div class="index-content">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg">
          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding left bottom medium-padding right bottom left">
      <div class="index-content">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg">
          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 small-padding left bottom">
      <div class="index-content">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 small-padding right bottom ">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="1" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row row-small-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="2" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right left bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="3" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="4" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 small-padding right left bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x205" alt="5" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure should be like

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is plunker code 
https://plnkr.co/edit/KbUTxzDRvnQjNYsH4wpm?p=preview